# In redux, preloading state using with combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am just getting introduced to redux, and am stucked with a problem of preloading the state for some time.

When using a single reducer, I was using the following code, and it used to work fine. Relevant snippets::

```
const head = (state = {}, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {

  case 'TOGGLE_VISIBLITY':
    if (state.head.content !== action.id) {
      return state
    }
    state.body.visible = !state.body.visible;
    return state;

    default:
      return state
    } 
 }

const heads = (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'TOGGLE_VISIBLITY':
  state.body = state.body.map(t =>
    head(t, action)
  );
 }
 return state;
}

export const store = createStore(heads, config);
```

But instead this I just changed to combinerReducers, and it started thowing JS errors.

> Unexpected keys "head", "body" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "heads". Unexpected keys will be ignored.

My change was::

```
const plannerApp = combineReducers({
   heads
});

export const store = createStore(plannerApp, config);
```

In case you wanna check the full code,please visit [here](https://github.com/AyanGhatak/planner/blob/develop/app/components/App.jsx).

Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks a lot in advance.. I appreciate your time and efforts...

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the preloaded state needs to match the structure of your reducers. Since you switched to using `combineReducers`, your state tree structure has changed. You now have a top level key of `heads` that has a child key of `body`, so you probably need to update your `config` to look like:

```
export default {
  heads: {
    body: {
      ...
```

As it is now, the `config` object contains top level keys of `head` and `body`, which do not have entries at the top level of your state tree.